# Inserting a Python datetime.datetime object into MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, datetime

I have a date column in a MySQL table. I want to insert a `datetime.datetime()` object into this column. What should I be using in the execute statement?

I have tried:

```
now = datetime.datetime(2009,5,5)

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table
(name, id, datecolumn) VALUES (%s, %s
, %s)",("name", 4,now))
```

I am getting an error as: `"TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"`
What should I use instead of `%s`?

Comment: you missed quotes around `%s`
`cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table
(name, id, datecolumn) VALUES (%s, %s
, '%s')",("name", 4,now))`

Answer (score 244):

For a time field, use:

```
import time    
time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

I think `strftime` also applies to `datetime`.

Comment: Also, make sure your column name isn't a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).  Took me  30 minutes to realize the name "current_date" was causing problems...ugh!

Comment: What is `time` in this example?

Comment: J McMahon: time is a Python module.

Comment: What if someone wants to fetch the only Year, Month, Day?

Comment: @PoojaKhatri time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

Comment: what's the argument (datetime)?

Comment: How many different things are called "time" in this answer? Where's the input value? Is that for now or something?

Answer (score 52):

You are most likely getting the TypeError because you need quotes around the datecolumn value.

Try:

```
now = datetime.datetime(2009, 5, 5)

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table (name, id, datecolumn) VALUES (%s, %s, '%s')",
               ("name", 4, now))
```

With regards to the format, I had success with the above command (which includes the milliseconds) and with:

```
now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You may not have quotes around `%s` in `pymsql`.

Comment: Quotes around the third %s cause error when I try this.

Answer (score 15):

Try using `now.date()` to get a `Date` object rather than a `DateTime`.

If that doesn't work, then converting that to a string should work:

```
now = datetime.datetime(2009,5,5)
str_now = now.date().isoformat()
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO table (name, id, datecolumn) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)', ('name',4,str_now))
```

Comment: Don't you need to add quotes around the string parameters i.e.  "... VALUES ('%s','%s','%s')"

Answer (score 15):

Use Python method [`datetime.strftime(format)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime), where format = `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`.

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table (name, id, datecolumn) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
               ("name", 4, now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))
```

### Timezones

If timezones are a concern, the MySQL timezone can be set for UTC as follows:

```
cursor.execute("SET time_zone = '+00:00'")
```

And the timezone can be set in Python:

```
now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

---

### [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html)

> MySQL recognizes DATETIME and TIMESTAMP values in these formats:
>
> As a string in either **'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'** or **'YY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'**
>   format. A “relaxed” syntax is permitted here, too: Any punctuation
>   character may be used as the delimiter between date parts or time
>   parts. For example, '2012-12-31 11:30:45', '2012^12^31 11+30+45',
>   '2012/12/31 11*30*45', and '2012@12@31 11^30^45' are equivalent.
>
> The only delimiter recognized between a date and time part and a
>   fractional seconds part is the decimal point.
>
> The date and time parts can be separated by T rather than a space. For
>   example, '2012-12-31 11:30:45' '2012-12-31T11:30:45' are equivalent.
>
> As a string with no delimiters in either 'YYYYMMDDHHMMSS' or
>   'YYMMDDHHMMSS' format, provided that the string makes sense as a date.
>   For example, '20070523091528' and '070523091528' are interpreted as
>   '2007-05-23 09:15:28', but '071122129015' is illegal (it has a
>   nonsensical minute part) and becomes '0000-00-00 00:00:00'.
>
> As a number in either YYYYMMDDHHMMSS or YYMMDDHHMMSS format, provided
>   that the number makes sense as a date. For example, 19830905132800 and
>   830905132800 are interpreted as '1983-09-05 13:28:00'.

Answer (score 3):

What database are you connecting to? I know Oracle can be picky about date formats and likes [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

**Note: Oops, I just read you are on MySQL. Just format the date and try it as a separate direct SQL call to test.

In Python, you can get an ISO date like

```
now.isoformat()
```

For instance, Oracle likes dates like

```
insert into x values(99, '31-may-09');
```

Depending on your database, if it is Oracle you might need to TO_DATE it:

```
insert into x
values(99, to_date('2009/05/31:12:00:00AM', 'yyyy/mm/dd:hh:mi:ssam'));
```

The general usage of TO_DATE is:

```
TO_DATE(<string>, '<format>')
```

If using another database (I saw the cursor and thought Oracle; I could be wrong) then check their date format tools. For MySQL it is DATE_FORMAT() and SQL Server it is CONVERT.

Also using a tool like [SQLAlchemy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLAlchemy) will remove differences like these and make your life easy.

Comment: I don't recommend using datetime.isoformat() because if you use a timezone aware object, the generated string includes timezone data and no longer matches the required mysql format.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just using a python datetime.date (not a full datetime.datetime), just cast the date as a string. This is very simple and works for me (mysql, python 2.7, Ubuntu). The column `published_date` is a MySQL date field, the python variable `publish_date` is `datetime.date`.

```
# make the record for the passed link info
sql_stmt = "INSERT INTO snippet_links (" + \
    "link_headline, link_url, published_date, author, source, coco_id, link_id)" + \
    "VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) ;"

sql_data = ( title, link, str(publish_date), \
             author, posted_by, \
             str(coco_id), str(link_id) )

try:
    dbc.execute(sql_stmt, sql_data )
except Exception, e:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    dt= datetime.now()

    query = """INSERT INTO table1(python_Date_col)
               VALUES (%s)
            """
    conn = ...... # Connection creating process
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(query,(dt))
```

Above code will fail as "datetime.now()" produces "datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 11, 1, 16)" as a parameter value to insert statement.

Use the following method to capture the datetime which gives string value.

```
    dt= datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
```

I was able to successfully run the code after the change...

Answer (score -1):

when iserting into t-sql

this fails:

```
select CONVERT(datetime,'2019-09-13 09:04:35.823312',21)
```

this works:

```
select CONVERT(datetime,'2019-09-13 09:04:35.823',21)
```

easy way:

```
regexp = re.compile(r'\.(\d{6})')
def to_splunk_iso(dt):
    """Converts the datetime object to Splunk isoformat string."""
    # 6-digits string.
    microseconds = regexp.search(dt).group(1)
    return regexp.sub('.%d' % round(float(microseconds) / 1000), dt)
```

Answer (score -1):

for example date is 5/5/22 convert it into mysql date format 2022-05-05 to insert record in mysql database
%m month
%d date
%Y Year of 4 digits
%y 2 digits

Code Below:

```
from datetime import datetime
now='5/5/22'
print("Before", now)
now= datetime.strptime(dob,'%m/%d/%y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print("After", now)
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table (name, id, datecolumn) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",(name, 4,now))
```

Output:

Before 5/5/22

After 2022-05-05
(mysql format you can easily insert into database)
[image: it will be inserted in mysql table]