# Inserting datetime into MySql db

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

I have a datetime value which is made by strptime function

```
import MySQLdb
a = time.strptime('my date', "%b %d %Y %H:%M")
```

There is a column in MySql db of type DATETIME. When I try to insert this value into db, I, obviously, get the error of

```
mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1305, 'FUNCTION time.struct_time does not exist')

INSERT INTO myTable(Date......) VALUES(time.struct_time(tm_year=2222, tm_mon=4, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=1, tm_min=2, tm_sec=4, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=118, tm_isdst=-1), ......)
```

How can I insert this value into db?

Comment: This should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136437/inserting-a-python-datetime-datetime-object-into-mysql

Comment: how? it's a datetime.datetime object.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are now passing in a `time.struct_time` object, something MySQL knows nothing about. You'll need to format the timestamp to a format MySQL understands. Unfortunately the `MySQLdb` library doesn't do this for you.

It'll be easiest using the `datetime` module, but you can do this with the `time` module too:

```
import datetime

a = datetime.datetime.strptime('my date', "%b %d %Y %H:%M")

cursor.execute('INSERT INTO myTable (Date) VALUES(%s)', (a.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),))
```

The `.strftime()` method call on the `datetime.datetime` object formats the information in such a way that MySQL will accept.

Doing the same task with just the `time` module:

```
import time

a = time.strptime('my date', "%b %d %Y %H:%M")

cursor.execute('INSERT INTO myTable (Date) VALUES(%s)', (time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', a),))
```

Comment: @Antimony: That was **not** a typo; there is a `a.strftime()` call in the sample code posted. I am a little upset with all the reviewers that accepted that suggested edit now.

Comment: I realized that. Sorry. I changed it back.