# Python MySQL Error 1064 inserting datetime string

Tags: python, mysql, datetime

I have the following python code:

```
now = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
#now = datetime.datetime.now()
query = """INSERT INTO bandwidth_by_second (current_time, down, up)  VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"""
data = (now, 1.0, 2.0)
cursor.execute(query, data)
```

My schema for this table is:

- current_time - datatime
- down - double
- up - double

When running this, I get the following error:

> _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use near 'current_time, down, up) 
>   VALUES ('2014-10-27 18:29:32', 1, 1)' at line 1")

I had thought I had formatted the date time wrong, but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136437/inserting-a-python-datetime-datetime-object-into-mysql) suggests otherwise.

What the heck is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It had to do with the column name in the database table. I changed `current_time`to `currenttime` and it started working.

Comment: You are a god to me. I just spent several hours trying to figure this out. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Use '%s' in quotes. It will work then :)

Comment: I see other answers that suggest the same thing. When I do that `query = """INSERT INTO bandwidth_by_second (current_time, down, up)  VALUES ('%s', %s, %s)"""`, the resultant error looks like `(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'current_time, down, up)  VALUES (''2014-10-28 08:11:52.306849'', 1, 1)' at line 1")`