# MySQL Python Date and List Error

Tags: python, mysql, date, longtext

I am having 2 issues with executing some MySQL statements in Python. Firstly I have a date column, which I have inserted other records manually with the format YYYY-MM-DD (e.g. 2016-03-15). However there is an issue with the formatting somewhere, I have attempted various different combinations of formatting using strftime etc.

I referenced [Inserting a Python datetime.datetime object into MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136437/inserting-a-python-datetime-datetime-object-into-mysql), but this didnt help.

```
import time 
formattedTime = datetime.datetime(3000, 12, 03)
formattedTime = formattedTime.date().isoformat()
a = 1
b = 2
c = 4
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO nodeStatistics VALUES(%s, %d, %d, %d, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'item1 item2 item3')" %(formattedTime, a, b, c))
cnx.commit()
```

The date field, is my primary key. I get the error hinting a NULL entry for 0000-00-00 (which is the default value when a NULL is entered), so I know that the "formattedTime" and corresponing "%s" are failing:
mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError: 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '0000-00-00' for key 'PRIMARY'

Secondly,  I have a list, listWords = list(), in my database I have set the corresponding type as longtext. I append items to during my programs execution, in the end I ' '.join(listWords) to convert the list to a space-seperated string, however when I replace the above with :

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO nodeStatistics VALUES(%s, %d, %d, %d, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, %s)" %(formattedTime, a, b, c, listWords))
```

I get the error :

mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'item1 item2 item 3' at line 1

Any help wouuld be appreciated!

Comment: I think you should use comma `,` instead of `%` in your case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not use string interpolation for SQL queries. Instead use parameter substitution, which for MySQL always uses the `%s` but is processed differently; and is separated from the values by a comma, instead of a substituting `%s`.

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO nodeStatistics VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'item1 item2 item3')", (formattedTime, a, b, c))
```

Comment: thanks Dan, that worked exactly how I intended, and the explanation was even more valuable