# Rewriting datetime in mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I'm having some trouble modifying a sql table that contains a date.

This is the code I'm running:

```
import pymysql
cnx=pymysql.connect(dbstuff)
cursor=cnx.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM devices ORDER BY ip_addr,Port ASC")
results=cursor.fetchall()
lst = [(i,)+line[1:] for i, line in enumerate(results, 1)]
values = ', '.join(map(str,lst))
query="DELETE FROM devices; INSERT INTO devices VALUES {}".format(values)
query = query.replace("None","NULL")
cursor.execute(query)
cnx.commit()
cnx.close()
```

If the date column in sql is NULL, this runs without a problem. If there is a date inserted into the field, I get the following error:

> "FUNCTION datetime.datetime does not exist."

When I look at the results of the sql select query, the date column value is converted to the following:

> datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 16, 11, 24, 4)

I assume this is a python thing and not a sql thing. I haven't been to find anyway to convert this to a format sql would understand.

Comment: Doing one statement at a time inside a transaction is probably less messy than this multi-query approach.

Comment: You need to `str` all the the items in the first set of `results`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting a Python datetime.datetime object into MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136437/inserting-a-python-datetime-datetime-object-into-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

For datetime values you may use this:

```
your_datetime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

This variable will hold a string value like this:

```
2018-05-06 21:14:37
```

And then use the following SQL command:

```
"INSERT INTO your_table (your_datetime_column) VALUES (str_to_date(\'%s\', '%%Y-%%m-%%d %%H:%%i:%%s'))" % (your_datetime)
```

**DO NOT USE FOLLOWING** - it won't work with the `.format()` method:

```
"INSERT INTO your_table (your_datetime_column) VALUES ({0})".format (your_datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling the **str** function of the datetime.datetime object will convert it to the string format required by SQL. It is currently trying to insert a python object.
Simply wrap your object like this:

```
dt = str(my_datetime_object)
```

Comment: In the code above, the entire set is a tuple of tuples, which is getting converting to a string in the command `values = ', '.join(map(str,lst))` as a whole. I can't figure out how to convert a single object in that tuple and within the values string, it still shows up as `datetime.datetime(etc)`.

Answer (score 0):

This error is raised when you pass invalid format date string in SQL query. Even a space in `'2018-05-01 11:02:02 '` can cause this error. The best way to get rid of it is to avoid string formatting while making sql queries.

```
c=db.cursor()
c.execute("INSERT INTO devices VALUES(%s,%s,%s)",(value1,value2,value3))
c.close()
```

If you are unknown that how many values will have then, you have to generate `(%s,%s...)` dynamically.

```
import pymysql
cnx=py

mysql.connect(dbstuff)
cursor=cnx.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM devices ORDER BY ip_addr,Port ASC")
results=cursor.fetchall()
lst = [(i,)+line[1:] for i, line in enumerate(results, 1)]
formatt=','.join(['%s']*len(lst))
query="INSERT INTO devices VALUES (%s)"%formatt
cursor.execute(query,lst)
cnx.commit()
cnx.close()
```