# Get filename and date time from string

Tags: python

I have file names in the following format: name_2016_04_16.txt

I'm working with python3 and I would like to extract two things from this file. The prefix, or the name value as a string and the date as a DateTime value for the date represented in the string. For the example above, I would like to extract:

filename: name as a String

date: 04/16/2016 as a DateTime

I will be saving these values to a database, so I would like the DateTime variable to be sql friendly.

Is there a library that can help me do this? Or is there a simple way of going about this?

I tried the following as suggested:

```
filename = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
        print(filename)
        filename.split("_")[1::]
        print(filename)
        '/'.join(filename.split("_")[1::])
        print(filename)
```

But it outputs:

```
name_2016_04_16  
name_2016_04_16  
name_2016_04_16
```

And does not really extract the name and date.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you made any effort for this yourself yet?

Comment: I can use the os.path module to get it to just that from the whole filepath, but I am stuck on getting those two values from the string that is left over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first strip the file extension, then I would split by underscore, removing the 'name' field. Finally, I would join by slash (maybe this value could be logged) and parse the date with the datetime library

```
import os
from datetime import datetime

file_name = os.path.splitext("name_2016_04_16.txt")[0]
date_string = '/'.join(file_name.split("_")[1::])
parsed_date = datetime.strptime(date_string, "%Y/%m/%d")
```

To make the date string sql friendly, I found this so post: [Inserting a Python datetime.datetime object into MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136437/inserting-a-python-datetime-datetime-object-into-mysql), which suggests that the following should work

```
sql_friendly_string = parsed_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested and update my post, however it only strips the extension and doesn't do the rest.

Comment: FlameDra: In your posted example, you printed the variable `filename` 3 times... I edited the answer to be a bit more clear

Answer (score 1):

How about simply doing this?

```
filename = 'name_2016_04_16.txt'
date = filename[-14:-4] # counting from the end will ensure that you extract the date no matter what the "name" is and how long it is
prefix = filename [:-14]

from datetime import datetime

date = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y_%m_%d') # this turns the string into a datetime object
```

(However, this works on Python 2.7, if it works for Python 3 you need to find for yourself.)

Answer (score 0):

You can split the filename on "." Then split again on "_". This should give you a list of strings. The first being the name, second through fourth being the year, month and day respectively. Then convert the date to SQL friendly form.

Something like this:

```
rawname ="name_2016_04_16.txt"
filename = rawname.split(".")[0] #drop the .txt
name = filename.split("_")[0] #provided there's no underscore in the name part of the filename
year = filename.split("_")[1]
month = filename.split("_")[2]
day = filename.split("_")[3]
datestring = (month,day,year) # temp string to store a the tuple in the required order 
date = "/".join(datestring) #as shown above
datestring = (year,month,day)
SQL_date = "-".join(datestring ) # SQL date
print name
print date
print SQL_date
```

Unless you want to use the datetime library to get the datetime date, in which case look up the datetime library
You can then do something like this:

```
SQL_date = datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

This is the most explicit way I can think of right now. I'm sure there are shorter ways :)

Apologies for the bad formatting, I'm posting on mobile.

Comment: I get a TypeError: join() takes exactly one argument (3 given) when I try to create date how you do.

Comment: sorry about that, was typing it out on my phone and couldn't test it.

Comment: @Lloyd Kirk has that short and elegant solution I mentioned in my reply :)