# How to convert DateTime object to SQL TIMESTAMP in python

Tags: python, sql, datetime, timestamp

I have a `datetime` object that I want to `INSERT` in an SQL database `TIMESTAMP` column.

However, the procedure always fails due to formatting mismatch.

The `datetime` object:

`date = datetime.datetime.strptime('2021-07-21 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

I tried to format it this way:

`datetime.datetime.timestamp(date)`

But it didn't work out, I think because the `timestamp()` function returns a `float`.

Is there a way to properly convert the `datetime` object to `timestamp`?

Comment: [This has already been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136437/inserting-a-python-datetime-datetime-object-into-mysql)

Comment: not really. This one converts to ```datetime```, but I want to convert ```datetime``` to ```timestamp```

Comment: Which is your target DBMS?

Comment: its mysql database

Comment: The top answer in the linked question above doesn't convert to datetime, it converts to string.  `.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` this has worked for me uploading to timestamp fields in several types of SQL (admittedly, never tried it in mysql)